# pandas read_csv with data and headers in alternate columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a generated CSV file that

1. doesn't have headers
2. has header and data occur alternately in every row (headers do not change from row to row).

E.g.:

```
imageId,0,feat1,30,feat2,34,feat,90
imageId,1,feat1,0,feat2,4,feat,89
imageId,2,feat1,3,feat2,3,feat,80
```

IMO, this format is redundant and cumbersome (I don't see why anyone would generate files in this format). The saner/normal CSV of the same data (which I can directly read using `pd.read_csv()`:

```
imageId,feat1,feat2,feat
0,30,34,90
1,0,4,89
2,3,3,80
```

My question is, how do I read the original data into a pd dataframe? For now, I do a `read_csv` and then drop all alternate columns:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
df=df[range(1, len(df.columns), 2]
```

Problem with this is I don't get the headers, unless I make it a point to specify them.

Is there a simpler way of telling pandas that the format has data and headers in every row?

Comment: There were probably some obscure business requirements that had defined the csv to be defined in such a way, was there no documentation or guidance with it? the answer below will work well if the columns are consistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select columns by indexing in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and set new columns names with get first row and pair values (assuming pair columns have same values like in sample data):

```
#default headers
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)

df1 = df.iloc[:, 1::2]
df1.columns = df.iloc[0, ::2].tolist()
print (df1)
   imageId  feat1  feat2  feat
0        0     30     34    90
1        1      0      4    89
2        2      3      3    80
```

Comment: You seem to build your solution on `df=pd.read_csv(file, headers=None)`. Forgive my maybe stupid question: Does `pd.read_csv` include some lazy mechanism that doesn't at first consume memory for all the redundant headers?

Comment: @Wolf - Honestly not idea.

Comment: I'm relatively new to the pandas world: Would you confirm that my answer shows a less resource hungry approach?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't measure but I would expect that it could be a problem to read the entire file (redundant headers and actual data) before filtering for the interesting stuff. So I tried to exploit the optional parameters `nrows` and `usecols` to (hopefully) limit the amount of memory needed to process the CSV input file.

```
# --- Utilities for generating test data ---
import random as rd

def write_csv(file, line_count=100):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        r = lambda : rd.randrange(100);
        for i in range(line_count):
            line = f"imageId,{i},feat1,{r()},feat2,{r()},feat,{r()}\n"
            f.write(line)

file = 'text.csv'

# Generate a small CSV test file
write_csv(file, 10)

# --- Actual answer ---
import pandas as pd

# Read columns of the first row
dfi = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, nrows=1)
ncols = dfi.size

# Read data columns
dfd = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, usecols=range(1, ncols, 2))
dfd.columns = dfi.iloc[0, ::2].to_list()
print(dfd)
```

Comment: I think, if you're going to read it line by line, you might as well create the dataframe instead of adding a new disk write and read.